# Formatting text with PHP

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way I can format a list so I can insert it via SQL?

My current list format is `test:test` and I want to be able to format it so it will insert into my database.

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`user`, `file`) VALUES
('test', 'test'),
('test2', 'test2'),
('test@test3.com', 'test3');
```

Is this possible by any chance?

```
<?
if($_POST['oldlist']){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE user='$_POST[oldlist]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo "exists";} else {

$sqlq = "INSERT INTO test (`user` ,`file`)
VALUES ('$_POST[oldlist]');";
$add = mysql_query($sqlq) or die(mysql_error());
if($add){echo "done";}else {echo "failed";}
}}
?>
```

Something by that means? I want to be able to post a list and have it insert into my database, but it has to be formatted first.

Comment: It's for my personal use, nothing public.

Comment: You can use explode() in php.

Comment: @sathish I know very little about explode.

Comment: what is the value of $_POST[oldlist]? is it contains value of both name and file.

Comment: @sathish I was just going to create a single field, and post it. I was attempting a textarea.

Comment: I don't understand - this looks like it could all be done within an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @OMG Ponies What do you mean? I'm not updating anything. I'm trying to insert a list based on my current format, and insert it into my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a nasty SQL injection flaw in your code. Make sure you escape your values! Here's how I would suggest you escape your code and insert it into your database:

```
<?php
// Use isset to determine whether there is a value present
if(isset($_POST['oldlist'])){

    $oldlist = $_POST['oldlist'];
    // Escape your data. Makes sure someone inject code that can jack your DB
    $oldlist_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($oldlist);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE user='$oldlist_esc'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        echo "exists";
    else {
        // I'll assume your data is line-delimited
        $oldlist = explode("\n", $oldlist);
        $new_oldlist = $oldlist;
        foreach($oldlist as $key=>$value) {
            $new_oldlist[$key] = explode(" ", $value, 1); // I'll assume each line is space-delimited

            // Escape the new data
            foreach($new_oldlist[$key] as $new_key=>$new_value)
                $new_oldlist[$kew_key] = mysql_real_escape_string($new_value);
        }
        $sqlq =    "INSERT INTO test (`user` ,`file`) VALUES ";

        // Build out the query
        $c = 0;
        foreach($new_oldlist as $value) {
            if($c++ > 0) $sqlq .= ',';
            $sqlq .= '("';
            $sqlq .= implode('","', $value);
            $sqlq .= '")';
        }

        $add = mysql_query($sqlq) or die(mysql_error());
        if($add)
            echo "done";
        else
            echo "failed";
    }
}

?>
```

It's fine to use variables inside strings (i.e.: "asdfasdf $myvar asdfasdf"), but remember to escape your data using `mysql_real_escape_string`. This keeps the user from injecting data like:

```
';DELETE FROM test WHERE true;--
```

which would effectively wipe your database. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If your $_POST has some paired values inside an array, try exploding each of the elements of the array by ":", joining them with the proper syntax for a single insert, then join the whole array for the multiple insert:

```
<?
// Just added 'olduser' as it seemed to go with WHERE user=... , change to your needs
if($_POST['olduser'] && $_POST['oldlist']){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE user='$_POST[olduser]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo "exists";} else {

foreach ($_POST['oldlist'] as &$each)
{
    $each = explode(":",$each);
    $each = "('".join("','",$each)."')";
}

$_POST['oldlist'] = join(",",$_POST['oldlist']);

// no semi-colon at end
$sqlq = "INSERT INTO test (`user` ,`file`) VALUES $_POST[oldlist]";
$add = mysql_query($sqlq) or die(mysql_error());
if($add){echo "done";}else {echo "failed";}
}}
?>
```

Anyway,be careful with your statements, I won't keep it without sanitizing the queries even for local usage.